# ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET MVC 2 tags on StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

All,

I want to get some higher ups thoughts on these two tags (soon to be 3 when ASP.NET MVC 3 starts to become more widely used).  Right now on SO, there is a large disconnect between the 2.  Most simply use the .NET MVC tag, others put both and in rare cases, the ASP.NET MVC 2 tag is the only one used.  Is there anyway that can we make this more consistent or provide any guidance in this area?  What about questions about MVC in general relating to the .NET implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suggest synonyms so for example `asp.mvc` will be remapped to `asp.net-mvc`

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-mvc/info

Comment: Hey, new undiscovered feature for me!

Comment: Synonym proposition system makes no sense because you need to have 5 votes. That cuts off 95% of users!