# Change tag asp.net-mvc-* to tags * and asp.net-mvc, if not already so tagged

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

The current tags describe two aspects of a question rather than one.  For example, routing is an ASP.NET feature that happens to be heavily used in ASP.NET MVC but is not restricted to it.  It seems more natural that a question tagged `asp.net-mvc-routing` be tagged with the two existing tags `asp.net-mvc` and `routing` rather than having a specific tag for an aspect of asp.net-mvc.  Likewise for `asp.net-mvc-controllers` and `asp.net-mvc-areas`, though in those two cases the connection is stronger to ASP.NET MVC.  In essence, I suppose I'm expressing a preference for multiple, single aspect tags over fewer, more specific tags.  Many, if not most, of the questions with these tags already are tagged with `asp.net-mvc`.

Related: [ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET MVC 2 tags on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62228/asp-net-mvc-and-asp-net-mvc-2-tags-on-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 1):

I somewhat agree. `asp.net-mvc-routing` seems like an error to me. There's no such feature.

But `routing` isn't the right tag, either. `asp-net-routing` would be closer to the mark

However, I'm unable to propose the more correct `asp.net-routing` as a tag synonym since the erroneous `asp.net-mvc-routing` has many more uses.